# iOS MPMoviePlayer how to remove all buttons & play video dynamically

Tags: ios, ios4, ipad

How can I remove all buttons(play,pause,fullscreen...) in a player view - like in all interactive magazines. so I could play video in page swipe or after some action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the controls by setting the [`controlStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW31) property of `MPMoviePlayerController` to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`. Rest of it, although unclear, look possible using gestures attached to the `view` property.